# How to swap table numbers in Word

Tags: microsoft-word

I have several tables with caption. To insert any table, I used to first insert a text box and then insert table inside it. And finally insert a caption for it. Now I have several such tables with caption (each inside its own textbox). Now I wanted to swap the position and table number of two of these tables say table 3 and 4. First, I swapped their position. Then to automatically regenerate their table numbers, I selected whole text in the doc and then hit F9 key to regenerate table numbers. But it did not regenerate table numbers for these swapped tables. So, now I have table 4 before table 3. How do I fix this?

PS1: I put tables and caption inside textbox, because when I tried it without textbox, caption used to appear at weird places far away from corresponding table, usually at the top of the page, even though the table itself is somewhere at the middle of the page.

PS2: Am using Word 2016